# Input dimension mismatch between dense layers and conv layers of imagenet while attempting transfer learning

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, imagenet

I am trying to train dense layers on top of the conv layers of InceptionV3.
But I'm unable to initialize the fully connected model. I'm getting a ValueError.

```
model_inc = applications.InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', 
                                     include_top=False)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=model_inc.output_shape[1:]))
model.add(Dense(256, activation= 'relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax'))
```

I expected the model to compile successfully but I get "ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (None, None, 2048). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model."

Comment: Be mindful, loading a model and then loading another may be causing auto-named layers to collide! Naming layers (sucks, and) works, or if you're running repeatedly, keras.backend.clear_session() is a handy fix.

Answer (score 0):

You want your input to go to your `model_inc` so you have to define the `input_shape` there. Something like the following should work

```
model_inc = applications.InceptionV3(input_shape=(224,224,3), weights='imagenet', 
                                     include_top=False)
model = Sequential()

# you need to add your base model
model.add(model_inc)

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation= 'relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax'))
```